# monit sumary not working when domain specified in use address

Tags: monit

When I specify an actual domain in my monitrc file like so:

```
set httpd port 2812 and
    use address domain.com # only accept connection from localhost
    allow localhost        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
    allow USER:PASS        # require user 'USER' with password 'PASS'
    allow @monit           # allow users of group 'monit' to connect (rw)
    allow @users readonly  # allow users of group 'users' to connect readonly
```

I'm not able to connect to monit locally through telnet or view any output using the 'monit summary' command.

When I change domain.com to localhost everything works fine. I'd like to have external access to monit especially since I'm using m/monit.

Comment: Did you try "use address IP" where IP is the IP address of the host?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the [monit documentation](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#host_and_network_allow_list) correctly:

> If you use this method together with a host list, then only clients from the listed hosts will be allowed to connect to the Monit http server and each client will be asked to provide a username and a password.

the `allow localhost` line will prevent anyone from connecting that isn't connecting *from* localhost.